# Symmetry of Hecke L-function zeroes

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

For the Riemann zeta function, it is known by the functional equation and $\zeta(s)=\overline{\zeta(\bar s)}$ that the zeroes of $\zeta(s)$ are symmetric about the critical line $1/2$ and the real axis.

Is the analagous statement true for Hecke L-functions? What about more general L-functions for which the functional equation is known?

Comment: No, the analogous statement is not true. The functional equation $s \mapsto 1-s$ describes the zeroes of the original $L$-function in terms of the corresponding $L$-function (that is, if $L(s,f)$ maps into $L(1-s, g)$ for whatever $g$). For conjugation, it depends. For instance, if $\chi$ is a real character, then $L(s,\chi)$ has zeroes symmetric about the real axis. But this is not the case if $\chi$ is an imaginary character.